# Google maps textsearch API is returning empty result

Tags: google-maps

I'm searching for top attractions in a 'CITY_NAME' using google textsearch API. Till yesterday it was returning data but when I'm trying now it is not returning results! whats going on here, why, I'm getting `ZERO_RESULTS`.

*Ex:*

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=top attractions in bengaluru&language=en&key=MY_API_KEY
```

I'm *expecting* it to return results like below

```
{
   "html_attributions": [],
   "results": [
      {
         "formatted_address": "Mavalli, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560004, India",
         "geometry": {
            "location": {
               "lat": 12.9507432,
               "lng": 77.5847773
            },
            "viewport": {
               "northeast": {
                  "lat": 12.9578032,
                  "lng": 77.59536344999999
               },
               "southwest": {
                  "lat": 12.9424072,
                  "lng": 77.57495644999999
               }
            }
         },
         "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_recreational-71.png",
         "id": "8ae4a9c5e9c2b40e58bf0c947e5502ff9ef71c29",
         "name": "Lalbagh Botanical Garden",
         "opening_hours": {
            "open_now": true
         },
         "photos": [
            {
               "height": 4032,
               "html_attributions": [
                  "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104005508763994607427/photos\">S.Ravindra Kumar</a>"
               ],
               "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAAYzPzHyHDleeTK4pM19jZ16SfDbG7lLZCrgr2wDEE_eNqDB5HdH670V0MXBRw03HH_HvFg0Rfe1dEZeG18NVVcxMUtpIOoHbN4a-csy0zqYRiJrTibapAiCxbYr8GKWrDEhBQAFmvTdSMKhoYbPlWmb-UGhSp70QBfrJgnUYSl5g_Ih24d80zIg",
               "width": 3024
            }
         ],
         "place_id": "ChIJHdPykcEVrjsRIr4v35kLEY4",
         "plus_code": {
            "compound_code": "XH2M+7W Bengaluru, Karnataka, India",
            "global_code": "7J4VXH2M+7W"
         },
         "rating": 4.4,
         "reference": "ChIJHdPykcEVrjsRIr4v35kLEY4",
         "types": [
            "park",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "user_ratings_total": 108174
      },
      {
         .......
         .......
      }
   ]
}
```

But I'm getting the below response.

*Response*

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Any kind of help will much be appreciated.

Comment: How are you encoding your URL? Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: hey, @MrUpsidown thanks for your quick reply. I have updated my question please check

Comment: You didn't answer my question: *How are you encoding your URL?*

Comment: no encoding I'm doing here

Comment: encoding is described [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/web-service-best-practices#BuildingURLs)

Answer (score 0):

Note that "attractions" is a very broad input; it can involve a wide variety of points of interests, place types etc. from museums to parks to zoos.

You should use a more specific place type in your queries. E.g.:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=top%20restaurants%20in%20bengaluru&language=en&key=KEY

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: yes, @evan I want a broad range of results. I want all the attractive places in a particular city. In the above example, the city is Bengaluru.

Comment: I understand, however, like I said, the Places API does not work with such broad query inputs. "Top attractions" can mean literally anything. You'll need to narrow down your query.